# What do you call someone who believes that their morals are pure?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, epithet-requests

I am trying to find the right word for a person that believes that he/she always acts with pure morals. (Sort of like a religious leader, especially in terms of pure heart or pure morals.)

If you have seen the movie [Dogville](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8rPllm4WEXw) by Lars von Trier, I am trying to describe a person like Grace. Up to a certain point in the movie, she truly believes and acts in accordance with her strong morals even when it is detrimental to her.

Here are a few words/phrases similar to what I am thinking of:

- self-righteous and holier-than-thou - this usually implies the person outwardly shows this but their actions are not in accordance with what they preach.
- martyr or saint might be closer to what I am looking.
- moral superiority - is close but it usually has a negative connotation similar to self-righteous.

Comment: Surely not a true martyr or saint; a characteristic of the latter, historically, is that they are well aware of their own sins and unworthiness and also do not presume to judge others.

Comment: Surely not a true martyr or saint; a characteristic of the former, historically, is that they are dead.

Comment: @Unrelated - Being dead is a characteristic of a Saint too. The catholic church doesn't beatify living people [citation needed.

Comment: @AndyT ah true true

Comment: If you wanted to describe someone who really is pure of heart and saintly in conduct, you could refer to him or her as a [Prince Myshkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prince_Myshkin), after the protagonist in Dostoyevsky's _The Idiot_. But then your audience would have to read _The Idiot_ to see how apt the term is. In any case, Prince Myshkin didn't act on the basis of believing he was good; he simply did what he believed was appropriate to do. On the other hand, a person who sincerely but falsely imagines that his or her morals and motives are pure might very well be termed _delusional_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call them a ***righteous*** person.

ODO:

> **[righteous](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/righteous)**
>   *ADJECTIVE*
>
> **1** *Morally right or justifiable*:
>   ‘feelings of righteous indignation about pay and conditions’
>
> ‘Over the decades, his choice of roles has defined the perception we
>   have of him as a decent, even righteous man of honour.’
>
> **1.1** *(of a person) morally good; virtuous*:
>   ‘he stood up for what he knew was right and died a righteous person’

Comment: But what about the case when the person is being mistreated and abused and still acts righteously? It's kinda inhumane.

Comment: @user2840286, that's the point, a truly righteous person won't change even if mistreated/abused.

Answer (score 2):

I think that [pious](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/pious) might work pretty well as an adjective:

> 1 Devoutly religious: ‘a deeply pious woman’
>
> 1.1 Making or constituting a hypocritical display of virtue:
>       ‘his pious platitudes’

And of course there is the noun [piety](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/piety) as well, to roughly define their belief structure:

> 1 [mass noun] The quality of being religious or reverent: ‘acts of
>   piety and charity’
>
> 1.1 [count noun] A belief which is accepted with unthinking conventional reverence:
>       ‘the accepted pieties of our time’

These have the advantage of spanning both "real religion" and put-on behaviors without a strong implication of one or the other, outside of context.

Answer (score 1):

How about *principled*?

M-W:

> [principled](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principled):
>   exhibiting, based on, or characterized by principle
>
> [*principle*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/principle): 1
>   a : a comprehensive and fundamental law, doctrine, or assumption b (1)
>   :  a rule or code of conduct (2) **habitual devotion to right
>   principles *a man of principle*** [emphasis added]

Answer (score 0):

Consider the term **altruistic**.

> Showing a wish to help or bring advantages to others, even if it results in disadvantage for yourself.
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/altruistic

Comment: This might bear too positive a connotation for what the OP needs.